# Private route resets context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React context where i hold information about logged user:

```
import React, { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface User {
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    rating?: number;
}

interface LoggedUserInterface {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: User;
}

interface IAuthContext extends LoggedUserInterface {
    setLoggedUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAuthContext>>;
}

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
};
// Default value for IAuthContext
const defaultAuthContextValue: IAuthContext = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {
        name: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        rating: undefined,
    },
    setLoggedUser: () => {}, // You might want to provide a default implementation
};

const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>(defaultAuthContextValue);

const AuthProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState<IAuthContext>(defaultAuthContextValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getWhoAmI() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profile/status", {
                    method: "GET",
                    credentials: "include",
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    setLoggedUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, isAuthenticated: data.isAuthenticated, user: data }));
                } else {
                    setLoggedUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, isAuthenticated: false, user: {} }));
                    console.error("Error checking authentication status:", response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (error: any) {
                setLoggedUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, isAuthenticated: false, user: {} }));
                console.error("Error checking authentication status:", error.message);
            }
        }

        getWhoAmI();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...loggedUser, setLoggedUser }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

And i have login page, i want to prevent alreadt logged user to navigate to /login.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Paper, TextField, Typography} from '@mui/material';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.css';
import {AuthContext} from "../context/AuthContext";

const Login: React.FC = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    const {setLoggedUser} = authContext;

    const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const loginUser = async () => {
        const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login';

        try {
            const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                setLoggedUser({
                    ...authContext,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                    user: {
                        name: data.name,
                        email: data.email,
                        rating: data.rating,
                    },
                });
                // Redirect to the desired page upon successful login
                navigate('/');
            } else {
                const errorData = await response.json();
                console.error('Login failed:', errorData.message);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error('Error during login:', error.message);
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        loginUser();
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <div id="login-wrapper">
                <Paper elevation={3} id="login-container">
                    <Typography variant="h2" align="center" gutterBottom>
                        Login
                    </Typography>
                    <form style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '16px', width: '100%'}}>
                        <TextField label="Email" type="email" variant="outlined" onChange={handleInputChange}
                                   name="email"/>
                        <TextField label="Password" type="password" variant="outlined" onChange={handleInputChange}
                                   name="password"/>

                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

For that, i am using private route:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
    isAllowed: boolean;
    redirectTo?: string;
    children?: ReactNode;
}

    export default function ProtectedRoute({ isAllowed, redirectTo = "/", children }: ProtectedRouteProps) {
        console.log("LOGGED IS " + isAllowed)
        if (isAllowed) {
            return <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
        }
        return children ? <>{children}</> : <Outlet />;
    }
```

Using it like:

```
function App() {

    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <AuthProvider>
                <Header/>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                    <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
                    <Route path="/login" element={
                        <ProtectedRoute isAllowed={authContext.isAuthenticated} redirectTo='/'>
                            <Login/>
                        </ProtectedRoute>}
                    />
                    <Route path="/howto" element={<HowTo/>}/>
                </Routes>
                <Footer/>
            </AuthProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When i login in login page, it redirects me to "/" page, however when i try to acces /login from url, it does not redirect me back to "/" as it should ( since user is already logged in ), i tried to check the condition but the `authContext.isAuthenticated` is always false when i try to acces login page with url `/login`.

Why is that? I have header where i display value based on if user is logged or not, and it works correctly. So the context should not change. So why is it false ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: if you're editing the url in the browser you are essentially performing a full refresh resetting anything that was done in memory, if you want to be able to edit the address bar and retain the logged in status you'll need to build something to do that eg storing the access token / auth details in a cookie or localstorage and pull it back into state then revalidate the login.